# Asp.net - How to find all gridview in my document

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have 4 gridviews in my aspx file. I can close their footer like below

```
if (admin == false){
  GridView1.ShowFooter = false;
        GridView2.ShowFooter = false;
        GridView3.ShowFooter = false;
        GridView4.ShowFooter = false; }
```

But i want to do that using "for" or "for each". Thanks for your helps already now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page has a Controls collection which contains all the top level controls on your page. Under these, each control also has a Controls collection, so a very naive implementation could look like this:

```
private void FindGridView()
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
  {
    GridView gv = ctrl as GridView;
    if (gv == null)
    {
      ParseCollection(ctrl);
    }
    else
    {
      gv.ShowFooter = false;
    }
  }
}

private void ParseCollection(Control parentCtrl)
{
  if (gv.Controls == null || gv.Controls.Count == 0)
    return;
  foreach (Control ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
  {
    GridView gv = ctrl as GridView;
    if (gv == null)
    {
      ParseCollection(ctrl);
    }
    else
    {
      gv.ShowFooter = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
void doSomething(Control c)
{
  GridView g = c as GridView;
  if (g!=null)
  {
    g.ShowFooter=false;
  }
  foreach(Control c2 in c.Controls)
  {
    doSomething(c2);
  }
}
```

Note that I haven't compiled the above. The idea is that you recurse through all of the controls in a certain container (Your page should do nicely), find the GridViews, do something with the gridview (set Showfooter to false, for instance), then recurse through that control's Controls array.

Side note:Someone pointed out that they didn't understand the significance of

```
GridView g = c as GridView;
```

Unlike a regular typecase

```
GridView g = (GridView)c;
```

the "as" keyword will return null if the cast isn't valid - ie, the control isn't a GridView.

**Edit:** 
Another (very readable) way to check the type:

```
if (c is GridView) g = c as GridView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine this code with ztech's approach

```
if (g.GetType() == typeOf(GridView))
{
    (GridView)c.ShowFooter = false;
}
```

This approach should be a little less work intensive as it won't try to cast every control on the page, only the ones whose type is GridView.